# How often should i make an Ajax request on a timer?

Tags: ajax

```
setInterval(function(){
// ajax request here
}, 9000);
```

I use a script like this to check for new notifications in the database and display them back on the page, giving the fact that for every user this check will be performed every few seconds or every minute i wonder if this can cause any performance issues.

Is it ok to make so many requests to the database or should i check for new notifications some other way?

Comment: Personally I would set a timeout in the callback function of the ajax request to avoid overlapping requests regardless of the time you set. But for real notifications you should look into server-side push instead of using polling.

Comment: You might want to check `html5 web worker` or `SSE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to consider:

- How often are updates *needed*?
- Can the server respond to them that frequently?

The first of those, only you can answer.

The second depends mostly on how much work the server has to do for each request, how many concurrent users you have, and how good the server hardware and network connection are.

---

The biggest risk with your current approach is that if the server can't respond that frequently, then you will have simultaneous requests in flight. If there is a real performance problem, you could end up with a queue of requests waiting to go out from the browser once you hit the maximum simultaneous HTTP request limit.

You can mitigate this risk by putting `setTimeout` in the success and error handlers for the request instead of sending them out every 9 seconds regardless.

---

An alternative approach would be to have the server initiate the sending of data when a notification became available. You could do this using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: So if i put `setTimeout` in the success and i handle the errors, will this be a reliable method for notifications? Or should i just use the other approach? 
And as for how often an update is needed, i don't really know, it depends on when users comment on a post or respond to comments.

Comment: It will avoid the specific problem I said it would avoid in the answer. I would. You know more about your users than I do.